# What does "each other player" mean on Unwinding Clock?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I am playing a four man free for all, when do my artifacts untap using [Unwinding Clock](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Unwinding%20Clock)'s ability? I'm having trouble understanding. The card says "each other player". If I am player one, are players two three and four "other players" or is player three the other player since it says "each other player"?

Comment: Why would player three be the only player referred to by "each other player"?

Comment: @Joe See my answer - I was confused too, but my wife figured it out for me!

Comment: @Joe, the OP seems to have confused "each other" (each player other than you) with the English phrase "every other" (which can refer to skipping half of the objects in the set)

Answer (score 14):

You untap your artifacts during player two's untap step, player three's untap step, and player four's untap step.

This isn't anything that's in the comprehensive rules or anything, it's just the meaning of the words on the card. "Each other player" could be explained as "each player who is not you" or to be really clear "every single player who is not you". None of those players is you, so you untap your artifacts during each of their untap steps.

I think you might have been wondering whether "each other" meant alternating (yes 1, no 2, yes 3, no 4...) like "every other" sometimes does. But "each other" doesn't ever mean that, so there's no ambiguity here!

You can see this demonstrated indirectly a few places in the rules, for example:

> 103.4. ... First, the starting player declares whether or not he or she 
>   will take a mulligan. Then each other player in turn order does the same. ...

Obviously that applies to all players, not alternating players! And of course, all the cards that say "each other player" wouldn't really make much sense if they meant alternating starting with you - in a two player game, that'd be just you.

Answer (score 0):

Each other player always means **every player that is not yourself**, not to be confused with **alternating players**. I've not come across a card that says this but I think this is what is confusing you?

Cards usually use **each other player** to signal every opponent *http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=grave+pact*, and **target opponent** to signal just one opponent. *http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=227064*

Comment: In a two-headed giant game, "each other player" does not mean the same thing as "each opponent". They are worded differently for a reason.

Comment: Also, your explanation could be a lot clearer - "every other" often means "alternating" in everyday English.