# Does Rageblood Shaman give itself +1/+1?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I was playing a game and this card came out and we couldn't decide if by "Other Minotaur creatures" it means not this creature, or if it included it.

Also, we assumed that it would give Trample to Minotaurs as soon as it was cast, rather than when its summoning sickness had passed.

Please can someone clarify for me, thanks!

[image: Rageblood Shaman]

Comment: I'm wondering what your group thought that the word 'other' meant in this context? I can't see how they could have possibly worded it less ambiguously.

Comment: @VolleyJosh "Minotaur creatures that are not this creature", perhaps

Comment: @murgatroid99, That's very clear, but no more than the original. If you read English, you need to know what "other" means, and they both share the same oddity of omitting the leading "the". It's also needlessly long for a common descriptor.

Comment: That comment was intended mostly to be tongue-in-cheek; I agree that the original wording is basically unambiguous. But this isn't the first time that people on this site have had trouble with that usage of the word "other," like [here](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/19152), and [here](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/19156). I'm not actually suggesting that the wording should change, but it's not obvious to everyone.

Comment: @murgatroid99, The first link is about a person thinking "each" could refer to only one the players, so the alternate wording wouldn't have helped. The alternate wording would avoid the second question, but it would cause another question to be asked instead ("What if the permanent ceases to be a creature?").

Comment: *Can this creature give its self trample?* - This creature **already has** trample. Read first line of that card

Comment: Wow, pretty angry community on here. I guess you're not beginner friendly. I'll ask questions elsewhere. Apologies.

Comment: @DavidYell If you edit your question to explain why you and your friends think *"other"* could possibly mean *"all"*, then I imagine you will get a more positive response. VolleyJosh commented about this within an hour after you posted, and you have yet to respond to him.

Comment: @DavidYell yes, this is an uppity bunch here.  But deeply knowledgeable.

Comment: @DavidYell Some people might've been less than diplomatic, and the discussion got sidetracked, but I think a lot of people are just trying to figure out how to explain something that seems to them like it's just the meaning of the words on the card. Asking you how you read it would usually help with that - either you'd say "I thought it meant X" and answers could explain otherwise, or you'd say "oh duh that's what it says, never mind" and either way things would be clear for you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, that's helpful. I'll be more verbose with questions including assumptions and reasoning in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Shaman has what is called a Static Ability. These kinds of abilities are active as long as their source is on the battlefield. So it will be active from the moment the Shaman enters the battlefield until the moment it leaves.

As for what it effects, "Other Minotaurs" means exactly that, any Minotaur other than the one with the ability gets the +1/+1 and trample. If you happen to control 2 of the Shamans they will each effect the other one, but they will not effect themselves.

In order for an ability like that to grant itself that ability it needs to drop the "Other" and just say "Minotaur creatures you control get +1/+1 and have trample." An example of this template is almost any [Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?subtype=%20[sliver]).

Also note that the Shaman already has trample, so the part of the ability that you should be caring about is the +1/+1.

> **604.1.** Static abilities do something all the time rather than being activated or triggered. They are written as statements, and they're simply true.

Comment: Re "These kinds of abilities are active as long as their source is on the battlefield", meaning it takes effect as soon as the Shaman *resolves* (not when it's cast, and not when it "loses summoning sickness").